# Binary tree inorder traversal Racket

Tags: algorithm, scheme, pseudocode, racket

I am trying to write the algorithm for inorder traversal for a binary tree using RACKET/DR. RACKET

```
 (define (print-records node number)
      (cond
      [(not (empty? node-left))(print-records (node-left node) number )]
      *Do This before moving to next IF clause*
      [(not (empty? node-right))(print-records(node-right node) number)]

      ))
```

I am trying to follow the following algorithm

```
InOrder(node)
if node is null return
InOrder(node.left)
Print(node)
InOrder(node.Right)
```

My problem is that through COND I can execute one expression and it will skip the rest. I tried to add two expressions under one it did not work either e.g ((a)(b)). I also tried to make a helper procedure but that did not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `cond` in a wrong way. Notice that you have to recursively traverse the left part of the tree, then visit the current node and then recursively traverse the right part of the tree - they're not mutually exclusive alternatives, the three steps need to be performed in precisely that order. Try something like this instead:

```
(define (print-records node number)
  (unless (empty? (node-left node))
    (print-records (node-left node) number))
  (print (node-value node)) ; replace this line with the actual printing code
  (unless (empty? (node-right node))
    (print-records (node-right node) number)))
```

Some explanations:

- `(unless <condition> <body>)` is just shorthand for `(cond ((not <condition>) <body>))`.
- The real work of the traversal is done between the two recursive calls, in this case I wrote `(print (node-value node))` as an example, replace that line with the actual printing code for the current node's value.
- It's not clear what do you intend to do with the `number` parameter, as it is it's just being passed around, unused.

Comment: It has a problem with the *print* function. It expects one expression but you have provided 2 extra (after the condition I think)

Comment: @Achilles as I said above: that's just an example. I don't know what printing function you're supposed to use, replace that line with the actual code. Please re-read my answer, I edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: In that line I basically want to call a function which prints output to user (it does a comparison between the "number" and the node value before choosing what to print.

Comment: My aim is to walk through a binary tree (inorder) and compare each node value to the "number" parameter and print a message accordingly.

Comment: That's all right :) I'll let you fill-in the details, what I wanted was to give you the correct structure of the solution and point you in the right direction, the rest is up to you ;)

Comment: The problem is it only executes the "unless" condition and its expression. It does not expect the other two expressions; print and the 2nd unless

Comment: What language are you using? it's one of those teaching languages that won't allow you to have more than one expression inside the body of a procedure? if that's the case, try packing all three expressions inside a `begin` form. It'll look like this: `(begin <unless1> <print> <unless2>)`

Answer (score 2):

Walking a binary-tree is a very general operation.  You can make a general procedure and then specialize it with the function to apply to each node.

```
(define (walker node function)
  (unless (empty? node)
    (walker (node-left  node) function)
    (function node)
    (walker (node-right node) function)))
```

Note: it is nice to check for `empty?` at the beginning of the function.

```
(define (print-records node number)
  (walker node (compose print node-value)))  ; ignore number, it seems.
```

You could also work this as:

```
(define (walking-with function)
  (letrec ((walker (lambda (node)
                     (unless (empty? node)
                       (walker (node-left  node))
                       (function node)
                       (walker (node-right node))))))
     walker))
(define print-records-for (walking-with (compose print node-value)))
(print-records-for node)
> ...
```